# Can't assign a tensor of type float to a variable of type float_ref in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I'm getting an error message like this

> tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Input 0
>   of node Assign_1 was passed float from _arg_prev_h_0_3:0 incompatible
>   with expected float_ref

prev_c is defined like this:

```
prev_c = tf.get_variable('prev_c', [1, params.cell_size], dtype=tf.float32)
```

and the assignment operator is like this:

```
prev_c.assign(next_c)
```

where `next_c` is a tensor of type `tf.float32`.

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Could you provide your entire code? If I run prev_c = tf.get_variable('prev_c', [1, 5], dtype=tf.float32)
next_c=tf.Variable([[1,2,3,4,5]], dtype=tf.float32)
prev_c.assign(next_c) I don't get any error.

Comment: It took me a few hours to figure it out. The problem was that I was accidentally including prev_c in the feed dict when calling session.run on the assignment operator. The cryptic error message certainly didn't me.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shared your sess.run portion, but I suspect that prev_c is also included as part of your feed_dict.
As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49479197/2110869), **you can't simultaneously assign and pass a variable as a feed_dict** in the same session run.